# Can I post the abstract of my article on Researchgate?

Tags: publications, citations

One of my articles has been published by Routledge: Taylor and Francis recently under a subscription publishing model.

Can I post the abstract of my accepted article in Researchgate as shown in [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259112431_Social_Workers'_Roles_in_Addressing_the_Complex_End-Of-Life_Care_Needs_of_Elders_with_Advanced_Chronic_Disease](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259112431_Social_Workers%27_Roles_in_Addressing_the_Complex_End-Of-Life_Care_Needs_of_Elders_with_Advanced_Chronic_Disease) ?

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you ask the publisher? If not, then asking the publisher seems to me how you would find an answer to something as potentially publisher-specific as this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. It's the abstract. You can generally read the abstracts of articles even if you don't have access to them.

This is clear enough that the Taylor & Francis [sharing policies page](https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/research-impact/sharing-versions-of-journal-articles/) doesn't mention it.